# Is it possible to convert multiple files in MediaConvert AWS service?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-media-convert

I have got a few files in s3 bucket and all of them need to be converted (3 output file per 1 input file).

Convertion rules are equal for all files.

Is it possible to do this? How can it be implemented on Node AWS sdk?

Do I need any extra service for it?

Comment: Could you update the post with what you've tried so far?

Comment: Tried to find option to convert many files via MediaConvert, but have not found yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a MediaConvert [JobTemplate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/using-a-job-template.html)

After this you can start one MediaConvert for each file in S3.

If you want to start this every time a file is added, for instance, your safest bet is to create a lambda that gets triggered when a new file is added to the S3 bucket and then start a new MediaConvert job using the saved JobTemplate.

Make sure you don't start a job for the outputs of the MediaConvert Job though.